# Error: 'ModalBottomSheetRoute' is imported from both

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

> Error: 'ModalBottomSheetRoute' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/bottom_sheet.dart' and 'package:modal_bottom_sheet/src/bottom_sheet_route.dart'.
>
> import 'material.dart' hide  ModalBottomSheetRoute;

Answer (score 29):

The reason behind the error is says both `material/bottom_sheet.dart` and `bottom_sheet_route` exports the `ModalBottomSheetRoute`.

```
'ModalBottomSheetRoute' is imported from both
'package:flutter/src/material/bottom_sheet.dart' and 'package:modal_bottom_sheet/src/bottom_sheet_route.dart'.
```

In order to fix this issue we have to hide one of the `ModalBottomSheetRoute`. since we need this to be imported from `bottom_sheet_route` we need to hide it from `material`

This is the way that we can fix,

Relace

`import 'package:flutter/material.dart'` with

`import 'package:flutter/material.dart' hide ModalBottomSheetRoute;`

in the following files.

1. `/Users/<usename>/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/modal_bottom_sheet-2.1.2/lib/src/material_with_modal_page_route.dart`
2. `/Users/<usename>/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/modal_bottom_sheet-2.1.2/lib/src/bottom_sheets/bar_bottom_sheet.dart`
3. `/Users/<usename>/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/modal_bottom_sheet-2.1.2/lib/src/bottom_sheets/material_bottom_sheet.dart`

Comment: This doesn't work for me.

Comment: THIS NOT WORKS.

Comment: Check your project dependency and remove the modal_bottom_sheet plugin which used it. It solved my issue.

Comment: this solution works.  hopefully it will be temporary...

Answer (score 27):

use
`modal_bottom_sheet: 3.0.0-pre`

This goes under your `dependency_overrides:` in the `pubspec.yaml` file such as:

```yaml
    dependency_overrides:
      modal_bottom_sheet: ^3.0.0-pre
```

Answer (score 17):

There's already a hot fix on the package

add this in the pubspec.yaml

```
 modal_bottom_sheet:
     git:
       url: https://github.com/followthemoney1/modal_bottom_sheet.git
       ref: main
       path: modal_bottom_sheet
```

It has already been pull requested but it has not been merged yet

Comment: link to MR: https://github.com/jamesblasco/modal_bottom_sheet/issues/311

Answer (score 16):

this error occur due to new flutter SDK update

Here is a Migration Guide for flutter 3.7 or later

**modal_bottom_sheet:**

- Update to modal_bottom_sheet: ^3.0.0-pre
- change `import 'packa ge:flutter/material.dart'` to `import 'package:flutter/material.dart' hide ModalBottomSheetRoute;` in every file, you are using the bottom sheet plugin.

Like this:

[image]

upvote the answer if it's helpful.

Comment: but I am not using modal_bottom_sheet in my project and i still have this issue

Comment: maybe some of your package are using modal_bottom_sheet as dependency

Answer (score 10):

If you're using the library package `country_code_picker` in your project change it with `country_picker`. The package uses an old version of modal_bottom_sheet and is conflicting.

Comment: or update `country_code_picker` to 3.0.0

Answer (score 5):

The problem there is both class named "ModalBottomSheetRoute" found in flutter material and plugin "modal_bottom_sheet"

this happened with me when try to use flutter v3.7.0 beta sdk

#Fix this issue

### Search for any file import"material.dart" at plugin "modal_bottom_sheet"

```
import 'material.dart';
```

### Replace by:

```
import 'material.dart' hide ModalBottomSheetRoute;
```

Comment: Abdullah Mahmoud i tried this solution but its not working for me. The problem is still there.

Comment: it doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 2):

In order to fix this issue we have to hide one of the `ModalBottomSheetRoute`. since we need this to be imported from `bottom_sheet_route` we need to hide it from `material`

This is the way that we can fix,

Relace

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart'
```

with

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart' hide ModalBottomSheetRoute;
```

in the following files.

Basic Path: `\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\modal_bottom_sheet-2.1.2\lib\src`

1. `\bottom_sheets\material_bottom_sheet.dart`
2. `\bottom_sheets\bar_bottom_sheet.dart`
3. `\material_with_modal_page_route.dart`

Answer (score 1):

Add `modal_bottom_sheet: ^3.0.0-pre` under dependecy_overrides: in pubspec.yaml
that will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use as prefix to import.

```
import 'package:modal_bottom_sheet/src/bottom_sheet_route.dart' as mbs;
```

then use the package like `mbs.YourClass()`

Comment: I recommend using suggested fix in the official merge request instead of changing your code with a soon obsolete solution.

Comment: @Cyber can you elaborate with example

Comment: Why would i change all the code with a prefix which would require refactor after the fix has been implemented.

Answer (score 0):

in addition to @Texv said,

if you are using smart_country_code_picker: ^0.0.2 also update to country_code_picker: ^3.0.0

it will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

if ypu are using country_code_picker package then upgrade it or any package that use modal_bottom_sheet upgrade it if yoou don't want to upgrade simply add below lines in pubspec file

```
dependency_overrides:
  modal_bottom_sheet: ^3.0.0-pre
```