# Modal Bottom sheet route issue in flutter 3.7.0

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-showmodalbottomsheet, flutter-upgrade

I have upgraded my flutter version from 3.3.10 to 3.7.0 and now getting the following error.

ModalBottomSheetRoute' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/bottom_sheet.dart' and 'package:modal_bottom_sheet/src/bottom_sheet_route.dart

I tried to follow this [Error: 'ModalBottomSheetRoute' is imported from both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74751803/error-modalbottomsheetroute-is-imported-from-both) but solutions didn't work for me.

Answer (score 3):

After the Flutter 3.7 update, my project started getting this error, however I don't use the `ModalBottomSheet` package, at least not directly, a another package I'm using, might be using it, so for now, the workaround (while a formal fix is in place) I added the following dependency override in the `pubspec` file, and problem solved

```
dependency_overrides:
  modal_bottom_sheet: ^3.0.0-pre
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   import 'package:modal_bottom_sheet/src/bottom_sheet_route.dart' as mymodal;
```

---

```
mymodal.showModalBottomSheet(
                context: context,
                // color is applied to main screen when modal bottom screen is displayed
                barrierColor: Colors.greenAccent,
                //background color for modal bottom screen
                backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
                //elevates modal bottom screen
                elevation: 10,
                // gives rounded corner to modal bottom screen
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                ),
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  // UDE : SizedBox instead of Container for whitespaces
                  return SizedBox(
                    height: 200,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: const <Widget>[
                          Text('GeeksforGeeks'),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );
```

Answer (score 1):

Make Sure you follow the Migration Guide for flutter 3.7

**modal_bottom_sheet:**

- Update to modal_bottom_sheet: ^3.0.0-pre
- Rename any ModalBottomSheetRoute class reference to ModalSheetRoute

**sheet:**

- Update to sheet: ^1.0.0-pre

have a look at the below link:

https://github.com/jamesblasco/modal_bottom_sheet/issues/325